# Javascript definir atributo na tag script com variável

Tags: javascript, atributos

Como passar uma variável para o atributo de um script, exemplo:

```
<script>
     token = "ablsicn05101dad10561" //exemplo. Esse token eu pego pela URL
</script>

<script 
  type="text/javascript"
  src="http://.."
  data-token=token>
</script>
```

O problema é que eu não consigo passar o valor da variável token, o que acontece é que data-token recebe o nome da variável como se fosse string, e não o valor dela.

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma forma de se fazer, apesar de que não sei se é a forma ideal ou se atende ao que você quer fazer com isso em específico:

```
<script>
  token = "ablsicn05101dad10561"
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.."> 
  document.currentScript.setAttribute('data-token', token)
</script>
```

Usando a propriedade `currentScript`, você consegue se referir à tag de script onde o código está, de forma simples e fácil. Então você usa o `setAttribute` para setar o valor que você quer dentro da tag.